# Problem setting dynamically the String text in a SpanLabel Constructor

Tags: label, codenameone

I am working on a Maven project.

I am building a user interface with a few `SpanLabel` objects. I set the text of the `SpanLabel` constructor dynamically, using `StringBuilder`. When I run the application the simulator screen turns completely black. When I set the `SpanLabel` text to a static `String` object, it works fine.
Any ideas what is wrong with this? Has anyone encountered this type of behavior before?

Comment: Yeah I think it would be a good idea to try testing this issue on the real device, to see if the bug appear there too.

Comment: @fnklstn My issue is that if the Simulator's screen goes black, then development becomes difficult. I only have a finite number of builds per month currently. Even if I had not this issue, it would still be a nuisance though.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the cn1 says that local (not server) builds are unlimited for free. I suggested to test the issue on the device because sometimes it might me simulator-only issue. Anyway, I just tried testing the similar code, and it seems to work fine. Can you post the example of your code please?

Comment: Well, in that "local" build case, although free, it still does not make much sense if I have to do this every time, right? It is time consuming.
Would you please provide code where you encountered this same issue to @Shai? He wants to check it out but I am not able to do so right now.
Thank you in advance. Regards.

Comment: I don't have this issue, it works fine by me - I ran a simple code based on what you described, to check. 
Android builds usually take 1-2 minutes for me, so if you already have your certificates generated, it's a 5 minutes work.

Answer (score 0):

Without code this is a complete guess but I'm assuming you did this in the main class. A Codename One app isn't available until init(Object) is invoked. So a lot of core services such as font dimension etc. aren't loaded yet.

`SpanLabel` relies on these services being there and if you invoke them in the constructor (that happens before `init(Object)`) then it will fail.

There's really no reason to do that. Just create components when you need them, no sooner.

Comment: Dear Shai, It is not in the main class. I am following the exact same partner I did as when I developed the previous application with Ant. It worked fine there.
I am not able to present code for this project, but it seems that others had the same issue as well. Perhaps you may ask them for their experience with the issue.
All I can tell you is that this unexpected behavior created a lot of distress in a situation I was on the clock.

Comment: Is this class invoked from the main class too early? Do you have any stack trace? Can you reproduce it in a test case so I'll have something more than guesses to work on?

Comment: Dear @Shai I am very sorry but I cannot provide anything right now. I will however try to reproduce the issue in another dummy project at some point later on. Then I will provide the code so as you may assess what the problem is.
Regards.